# sending data to fuelphp with angular4

Tags: angular, http, fuelphp

I send data to fullphp like this

```
let body = JSON.stringify({ product : 120 });
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

this.http.post(url, body, options).subscribe(
```

In fuelphp with Input::all() , i get this

```
{ '{"product":9350,"versioncode":610}': '' }
```

if i use content-type application:json , i got nothing in fuelphp side

how i must fix sending data in angular side that fuelphp can get it .

Comment: use in you controller?

Comment: i use http in my service

Answer (score 0):

Use `Input::json()` instead.

> The json method returns a json_decoded (and cleaned) value from the json request body.

https://fuelphp.com/docs/classes/input.html#/method_json